# Mysql FULL JOIN in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, collection

How can i execute something like full join in magento 2 then set query data in my collection. Below i try to do somethig.

```
$joinLeftCustomerSql = $connection
        ->select()
        ->from("$webSubscriberTable AS web_subscriber", ['token'])
        ->joinLeft(['customer' => $customerTable], 'web_subscriber.customer_id=customer.entity_id', 'email');

    $joinRightCustomerSql = $connection
        ->select()
        ->from("$webSubscriberTable AS web_subscriber", ['token'])
        ->joinRight(['customer' => $customerTable], 'web_subscriber.customer_id=customer.entity_id', 'email');

    $collection->getSelect()->reset()->union([$joinLeftCustomerSql, $joinRightCustomerSql]);
```

It is proper query but latter i have next problem `No table has been specified for the FROM clause`. After research i found out that magento can't do query `COUNT(*)` with my query and i need to build something like this:

SELECT * FROM (myquery) AS test

myquery -  `$collection->getSelect()->reset()->union([$joinLeftCustomerSql, $joinRightCustomerSql]);`

and i try execute this query

```
$fullSqlToUnion = $connection->select()->union([$joinLeftCustomerSql, $joinRightCustomerSql]);

    $collection->getSelect()->reset()->from($fullSqlToUnion);
```

But it don't work because magento make quote around my query in `FROM`.

Answer (score 1):

`$collection->getSelect()->reset()->from($fullSqlToUnion, '*');`